# How to solve syntax of the command is incorrect error in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am using the following code in batch file.
I am getting "Syntax of the command is incorrect " error.

Please help me how to solve this.

Thanks in advance...

```
@echo off
For /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%A IN (proconfig.properties) DO 
( 
IF "%%A"=="dbUsername" 
set dbUsername=%%B
) 

echo %dbUsername%

pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the opening parenthesis for the block of code after the `do` clause must be in the same line that the `do`.  And it is the same for the `if` command. Also, to retrieve two tokens with the `for` command, it is necesary to indicate it in the `tokens` clause

```
@echo off
For /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A IN (proconfig.properties) DO ( 
    IF "%%A"=="dbUsername" set dbUsername=%%B
) 

echo %dbUsername%

pause
```

Answer (score 2):

There's supposed to be a `(` right after the `DO` and increment the `tokens`.  Also, your `IF` statement need parenthesis as well.  See below:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
For /F "tokens=1-2 delims==" %%A IN (proconfig.properties) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="dbUsername" (
        set dbUsername=%%B
    )
) 

echo %dbUsername%

pause
```